# Using declaration merging to alter overload of `next` function in Express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, overloading

I would like to alter the type definition for the `NextFunction` when using Express, so that when invoking `next()` with an argument to trigger the global error handler, Intellisense can show the properties for the object that my error handler is expecting.

I have the following interface for what an object passed in to `next` should look like:

```
interface MiddlewareError {
  msg: string,
  err: Error | string,
  code?: number
}
```

Express already has a definition for `NextFunction` that takes in an `err` parameter of type `any`, but I want to augment it so that instead, the `err` parameter uses my `MiddlewareError` type.

---

I tried adding this to a custom type definition file:

```
declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
  export interface NextFunction {
    (err?: MiddlewareError): void;
  }
}
```

And it does work *initially* when I just write out `next()`, but as soon as I pass in an argument, it reverts back to the original type definition:

[image: Invoking next with no argument]

[image: Invoking next with object argument]

---

Is it possible to do this without doing something like copying/modifying the entire Express declaration file and using that instead? It would be very helpful to be able to see what should be passed to the `next` function instead of having to just remember, especially when working with multiple developers.